# Use variables for more than one output? [ PHP Functions ]

Tags: php, preg-replace, this

I'm currently a beginner developer and have just started my first big project whilst I have spare time, What I'm trying to do is basically write variables to a html/tpl document, Which I have currently got working, Here is my code:

```
private function index(){
    $username = 'MyUsername';
    $onlineTime = 'MyOnlineTime';
    $this->setParams('Username', $username); // $username Will be replaced by database queried results once completed.
}
```

And here is the setParams function.

```
function setParams($item1, $item2){

    ob_start();
    $theme = 'default';
    include_once T . '/'.$theme.'/index.php';   // T . is defined at the beginning of the document.
    if ((($html = ob_get_clean()) !==  false) && (ob_start() === true))
    {
    echo preg_replace('~{(['.$item1.']*)}~i', ''.$item2.'', $html, 1);
    }
    }
```

And here is the coding inside the html/tpl document.

```
{username} has been online for {onlineTime} Hours
```

This is probably a very simple code for some of you but as this is my first attempt this is all I can do.

What I would like to do is have it so you can setParams as many times as you want without changing the $variable names like so:

```
private function index(){
    $username = 'MyUsername';
    $onlineTime = 'MyOnlineTime';
    $this->setParams('Username',$username);
    $this->setParams('OnlineTime', $onlineTime);
}
```

whilst keeping the `setParams($item1, $item2)`

But as you can imagine this just cuts the code completely. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I've been searching all day without any real luck.

Thanks In Advance,

Ralph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a class with a static method;

```
<?php
class Params {

    public static $params = array();

    public static function setParam($key, $value) {
        self::$params[$key] = $value;
    }

    public static function getParam($key) {
        if (isset(self::$params[$key])) {
            return self::$params[$key];
        }
    }

}

// Usage

// Set Username
Params::setParam("username", "JohnDoe");
Params::setParam("password", "12345");

echo Params::getParam("username");
echo Params::getParam("password");
```

Comment: Thanks for super fast reply, Haven't been able to reply as I've been super busy. tried your method, Kicks out error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'setParam' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) ", If I'm correct you forgot to define function on both functions, e.g public static getParam($key) = public static function getParam($key), So I added that then it kicks out another error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' " Which I located to "self::params[$key] = $value;"

Comment: I've updated the original code, as I was in a rush when I wrote it and didn't have time to test. I'd missed 'function' off the method declarations

Comment: Thanks mate, works like a charm, But what would be the best way to filter the params so I could use them to inject into my html, e.g Params::setParam("username", "JohnDoe"); Would be called into the html document by using {username}.  Cheers, Ralph